# Generate random String in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.3

I'm using this SQL query to generate random value in PostgreSQL

```
chr(ascii('B') + (random() * 25)::integer)
```

How I can generate 15 characters random String using the same query?

Comment: How about concatenating it together 15 times?

Comment: @GordonLinoff: Never underestimate the power of brute force.

Comment: Can you give some example?

Answer (score 56):

Another solution that's pretty easy to read (perf should be reasonable, but no benchmarks were performed):

```sql
select substr(md5(random()::text), 1, 25);
```

Could be uppercased if you prefer:

```sql
select upper(substr(md5(random()::text), 1, 25));
```

Comment: Please note the behavior of PostgreSQL's `substr`. If you want to get the first 25 characters, please use `select substr(md5(random()::text), 1, 25)`, the first parameter `from` of `substr` refers to the character from starts and is calculated from 1. If you specify 0, the final result of `substr` will be one less character, because there is no character in the 0 position, it will assume you have it and return nothing.

Answer (score 22):

Here is my contrib

```
postgres=# SELECT array_to_string(array(select substr('ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789',((random()*(36-1)+1)::integer),1) from generate_series(1,50)),'');
                  array_to_string                   
----------------------------------------------------
 4XOS6TQG5JORLF3D1RPXUWR2FQKON9HIXV0UGH0CQFT1LN5D4L
(1 row)
```

It lets you specify the set of allowed characters and the length of the string.

Comment: `(random()*(36-1)+1)::int` will round a random number between 1 and 36 to the nearest integer. This means that the frequency of the first and last characters is about half that of the rest. You can use `floor(random()*36)::int+1` instead.

Answer (score 11):

This will give you a random word of length 15 consisting of the letters configured in the source values constant

```sql
select
  string_agg(substr(characters, (random() * length(characters) + 1)::integer, 1), '') as random_word
from (values('ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789')) as symbols(characters)
  -- length of word
  join generate_series(1, 15) on 1 = 1
```

EDIT: to obtain multiple random words you can use the following:

```sql
with symbols(characters) as (VALUES ('ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789'))
select string_agg(substr(characters, (random() * length(characters) + 1) :: INTEGER, 1), '')
from symbols
join generate_series(1,8) as word(chr_idx) on 1 = 1 -- word length
join generate_series(1,10000) as words(idx) on 1 = 1 -- # of words
group by idx
```

Comment: This solution can be highly performant when updating an existing dataset too, really like it

Comment: `select min(n), max(n) from (select (random() * length('ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789') + 1)::int n from generate_series(1, 10000000)) t0` returns values 1 to 63, inclusive. That means the call to `substr` may return an empty string, which will cause the returned value to be less than 8 characters. Just a caveat, good solution nonetheless.

Answer (score 6):

Yes can do this by single query also but if you want every char should be separate according to range then above is solution

```
SELECT array_to_string(ARRAY(
            SELECT chr((ascii('B') + round(random() * 25)) :: integer) 
            FROM generate_series(1,15)), 
             '');
```

Answer (score 5):

I use this, for generating random strings...

If you dont mind dashes and have the uuid extension enabled...

```
select substr(uuid_generate_v4()::text,1,15);
```

e.g. to generate a random string in the name column, i will use

```
select concat('name-', substr(uuid_generate_v4()::text,1,10)) as name;
```

e.g. `name-91fc72dc-d`

else, use the excellent md5 example from @fncomp

nb: To enable the uuid extension

```
create extension if not exists "uuid-ossp";
```

Comment: Or you use `gen_random_uuid()` which is core since Postgres 13+, no extension needed, making this for example `SELECT substr(gen_random_uuid()::text, 1, 8)`.

Answer (score 4):

### For me the most convenient way is to create a `function`:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION random_string(int) RETURNS TEXT as $$
SELECT substr(md5(random()::text), 0, $1+1);                 
$$ language sql;
```

The function is named `random_string`
and It takes `string length` as an argument.

### And then I use this `function` anywhere I want

###### Just see the result:

```sql
select random_string(6);
```

###### Make a single insert:

```sql
insert into users values(nextval('users_sequence'), random_string(6), random_string(6));
```

###### Generate multiple rows with random data:

```sql
do $$
begin
for i in 1..100 loop
insert into users values(nextval('users_sequence'), random_string(6), random_string(6));
end loop;
end;
$$;
```

and so on.

Answer (score 3):

I tried to use solution from @Bennit
but noticed some flaws. The random part is calculated a bit wrongly, that leads wrong results: the resulting lenght is differs (shorter) than desired.

[took a quick look at the @lyndon-s version - most probably it also has the same drawback]

So here is updated version of @bennit version:

```
select
string_agg(substr(characters, (random() * length(characters) + 0.5)::integer, 1), '') as random_word
from (values('ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789')) as symbols(characters)
-- length of word
join generate_series(1, 15) on 1 = 1
```

And here is demonstration why the change is required:

Corrected:

```
select n,count(*) from (
select (random() * 10 + 0.5)::integer as n from dbfiles
join generate_series(1, 100000) on 1 = 1
) as s group by n
order by 1;
```

Original:

```
select n,count(*) from (
select (random() * 10 + 1)::integer as n from dbfiles
join generate_series(1, 100000) on 1 = 1
) as s group by n
order by 1;
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is the idea:

```
select (chr(ascii('B') + (random() * 25)::integer) ||
        chr(ascii('B') + (random() * 25)::integer) ||
        chr(ascii('B') + (random() * 25)::integer) ||
        chr(ascii('B') + (random() * 25)::integer) ||
        chr(ascii('B') + (random() * 25)::integer) ||
        chr(ascii('B') + (random() * 25)::integer) ||
        chr(ascii('B') + (random() * 25)::integer) ||
        chr(ascii('B') + (random() * 25)::integer) ||
        chr(ascii('B') + (random() * 25)::integer) ||
        chr(ascii('B') + (random() * 25)::integer) ||
        chr(ascii('B') + (random() * 25)::integer) ||
        chr(ascii('B') + (random() * 25)::integer) ||
        chr(ascii('B') + (random() * 25)::integer) ||
        chr(ascii('B') + (random() * 25)::integer) ||
        chr(ascii('B') + (random() * 25)::integer) 
       ) as Random15
```

Comment: Is there any simple solution?

Answer (score 1):

Here's my PL/pgSQL take:

- there is an option to generate texts in english or russian symbols, and it's easy to expand for more languages;
- optional usage of digits, punctuation symbols, whitespaces and linebreaks;

> ```
> create or replace function random_string (
>     str_length integer, lang varchar(2) default 'en', 
>     w_dig boolean default true, w_punct boolean default true, 
>     w_space boolean default false, w_newline boolean default false
> )
>
> returns text
> language plpgsql
> as $function$
>      declare
>          chars_eng text[] := '{A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,K,L,M,N,O,P,Q,R,S,T,U,V,W,X,Y,Z,a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l,m,n,o,p,q,r,s,t,u,v,w,x,y,z}';
>          chars_rus text[] := '{А,Б,В,Г,Д,Е,Ё,Ж,З,И,Й,К,Л,М,Н,О,П,Р,С,Т,У,Ф,Х,Ц,Ч,Ш,Щ,Ъ,Ы,Ь,Э,Ю,Я,а,б,в,г,д,е,ё,ж,з,и,й,к,л,м,н,о,п,р,с,т,у,ф,х,ц,ч,ш,щ,ъ,ы,ь,э,ю,я}';
>          chars_dig text[] := '{}';
>          chars_punct text[] := '{}';
>          chars_space text[] := '{}';
>          chars_newline text[] := '{}';
>          chars_final text[] := '{}';
>          result text := '';
>          i integer := 0;
>     begin
>
>         -- checking string length arg
>         if str_length < 0 then
>             raise exception 'Length of string cannot be a negative value';
>         end if;
>
>         -- checking chars selection
>         if w_dig = true then
>             chars_dig := '{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9}';
>         end if;
>         if w_punct = true then
>             chars_punct := string_to_array(E'!d"d#d$d%d&d\'d(d)d*d+d,d-d.d/d:d;d<d=d>d?d@d[d\\d]d^d_d`d{d|d}d~','d');
>         end if;
>         if w_space = true then
>             chars_space := string_to_array(' ',',');
>         end if;
>         if w_newline = true then
>             chars_newline := string_to_array(E'\r\n',',');
>         end if;
>
>         -- checking language selection
>         if lang = 'en' then
>             chars_final := chars_eng||chars_dig||chars_punct||chars_space||chars_newline;
>         elsif lang = 'ru' then
>             chars_final := chars_rus||chars_dig||chars_punct||chars_space||chars_newline;
>         else 
>             raise exception 'Characters set for that language is not defined';
>         end if;
>
>         -- filling the string
>         for i in 1..str_length loop
>             result := result || chars_final[1 + round(random() * (array_length(chars_final, 1) - 1))];
>         end loop;
>
>         -- trimming extra symbols that may appear from /r/n usage
>         if length(result) > str_length then
>             result := left(result, str_length);
>         end if;
>
>         -- getting the result
>         return result;
>
>     end;
> $function$ ;
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Throwing in my 2c here. I needed random strings to do some benchmarks, so all that really mattered to me was that the strings were unique from each other.

```
select rpad(generate_series::varchar, 1000, 'hi') from generate_series(1,10);
```

rpad - pad right till length(1000), padded with 'hi'
generate_series(1,10) - generate 10 rows

Combining with an answer above, you could also do this:

```
select rpad(generate_series::varchar, 1000, md5(random()::text)) from generate_series(1,10)
```

That makes sure you have 200 chars, or whatever the desired length is.

Answer (score 0):

Well how about a recursive CTE. Combine with generate series to get however many you want.

```
with recursive brs(rstg, n) as 
     ( select chr(ascii('B') + (random() * 25)::integer), 1
         from generate_series(1,50)    --- or however many you want
       union all 
       select rstg || chr(ascii('B') + (random() * 25)::integer), n+1
         from brs 
        where n<= 15 
     )
select rstg 
  from brs
 where n=15;
```

Answer (score 0):

With orafce extension installed, you have an handy dbms_random.string()

Example for 15 characters from A to Z:

```
postgres=# create extension orafce;
CREATE EXTENSION
postgres=# select dbms_random.string('U',15);
     string
-----------------
 YCSPRBOFKXPCBQI
(1 row)
```

More info:
https://www.yugabyte.com/blog/generate-random-text-strings-in-postgresql/

Answer (score 0):

Random upper case string with in range random length:

```
UPPER(SUBSTRING(MD5(concat(now(),RANDOM())) FOR RANDOM()*2+5))
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution that expands on the original question and contains multiple character sets ([A-Z][a-z][0-9]). This solution is around ~20% faster according to my (non-scientific) measurements than the solution mentioned by @Bennit.

```sql
select array_to_string(array(
    select chr(
        case
            when n<10 then ascii('0')+n
            when n<36 then  ascii('a')+(n-10)
            else ascii('A')+(n-36)
        end
    ) from (
        select (random()*61)::int as n from generate_series(0, 20)) x
    ), '') as random_str
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm using encode(md5(gen_random_uuid()::text)::bytea,'base64')

For context, here's how I'm generating a base64-encoded secret for JWT token generation for Postgrest:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.exec(sql text)
RETURNS VOID AS 
$BODY$
BEGIN 
 EXECUTE sql; 
END 
$BODY$ LANGUAGE 'plpgsql';

select public.exec('
ALTER DATABASE mydb
SET "app.jwt_secret" 
TO ''' || encode(md5(gen_random_uuid()::text)::bytea,'base64') || ''';');

select current_setting('app.jwt_secret');
```